# Issues using php's PDOStatement::execute/fetch/rowCount to test existence of values in database?

Tags: php, mysql, validation, pdo

I'm having an issue with one of my classes (I believe). On a high level, I'm sending a form to a php file that initiates a class. By accessing several of it methods, it determines whether or not a value is in the database. If it is, it returns a boolean.

Here's the code that I believe is the issue:

```
public function territoryCheck($numberOut)

    {

        $this->numberOut = $numberOut;



        //Execute test

        $this->checkConnect();

        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT t_id FROM Territory WHERE t_id = :param1");

        $stmt->bindParam(':param1', $this->numberOut);

        $stmt->execute();   
        $count = $stmt->rowCount();



        //Determine value of test

        if($count == 0)

        {

            return FALSE;

        }   

    }



    public function publisherCheck($lName, $fName)

    {

        $this->lName = $lName;

        $this->fName = $fName;



        //Execute test

        $this->checkConnect();

        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT p_id FROM People WHERE lastName = :param1 AND firstName = :param2");

        $stmt->bindParam(':param1', $this->lName);

        $stmt->bindParam(':param2', $this->fName);

        $stmt->execute();
        $count = $stmt->rowCount();



        //Determine value of test

        if($count == FALSE)

        {

            return FALSE;

        }

        else

        {

            $dummyvar = $stmt->fetch();

            $this->p_id = implode($dummyvar);

        }



    }



    public function isTerritoryOut($numberOut)

    {

        //Execute test

        $this->checkConnect();

        $this->numberOut = $numberOut;

        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT t_id FROM checkIn WHERE t_id = :param1");

        $stmt->bindParam(':param1', $this->numberOut);

        $stmt->execute();
        $count = $stmt->rowCount();



        //Determine value of test

        if($count != 0)

        {

            return TRUE;

        }   

    }
```

There are three methods, each are a test that will return either true or false. 
I was testing with execute(), fetch(), and finally rowCount() to try to emulate the values I want. Neither seem to work. Here's the code that calls these methods:

```
//Begin tests

    $checkOut->territoryCheck($numberOut);

    if($checkOut == FALSE)

    {

        $fail = "Territory number ".$numberOut." does not exist in our records. Please enter a valid territory. For more information, navigate to About.<\ br>";

    }



    $checkOut->publisherCheck($lName, $fName);

    if($checkOut == FALSE)

    {

        if($fail !== "")

            $fail .= "The publisher, ".$fName." ".$lName.", is not in our records. For more information, navigate to About.<\ br>";

        else

            $fail = "The publisher, ".$fName." ".$lName.", is not in our records. For more information, navigate to About.<\ br>";

    }



    $checkOut->isTerritoryOut($numberOut);

    if($checkOut === TRUE)

    {

        if($fail !== "")

            $fail .= "Territory number ".$numberOut." is currently checked out. Either the wrong number was entered or the territory hasn't been properly checked in.<\ br>";

        else

            $fail = "Territory number ".$numberOut." is currently checked out. Either the wrong number was entered or the territory hasn't been properly checked in.<\ br>";

    }
```

For clarity, fail was set to "" earlier in the code. What happens is that it goes through all of these tests as if they had passed when I purposely create situations that should have failed. For instance, I only have territory numbers 1-130 in my database. If I put in 150, it essentially tells me that it exists.

I'm not sure what is going on, typecasting? == vs. ===?, etc.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must admit, the cause is a rather obvious question that is so obvious I didn't even consider it. In each test, I simply call the method without assigning any variable to accept the return value(i.e `$checkOut->publisherCheck();` instead of `$test = $checkOut->publisherCheck();`. Regardless, it works now.